# Filter and search DataGridView connected to a MS Access database in C#

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, filter, ms-access-2010

I use this code to filter and search a `DataGridView` connected to a MS Access database in C#, but when I enter anything into the textbox, every row of data in the `DataGridView`  disappears - any help?

This code to appear in datagridview

```
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AMR\Desktop\ABBagain-Copy.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from Query1";

                command.CommandText = query;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt;
                dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                da.Fill(dscontects);
                connection.Close();
```

and this in textbox

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("SerialNumber LIKE '%{0}%'",textBox1.Text);
        table1DataGridView.DataSource = dv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing % with *?  so your code would look like 
`dv.RowFilter = string.Format("SerialNumber LIKE '*{0}*'",textBox1.Text);`
the reason i say this is because access SQL wildcard character is * and not %

also im assuming you have the textbox code on a text_changed event?  I would consider changing that to be something that would hit the database a little less frequently.  maybe have a button or even textbox exit event.

Comment: i replaced % by * but nothing change

Comment: what do you get if you just put a "real value" in the LIKE statement?  for example, remove the "%" and/or the "*" so it would read `LIKE 'value'`
does anything get returned?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this solution:

```
string query = "select * from RecordsSheet where [SerialNumber] like('" + textBox1.Text + "%')";
```

Answer (score 0):

put all this code inside textbox keyup and make some changes like database and field name

string strProvider="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data      Source=Gym.accdb";

```
      string strSql = "Select * from cust";

      OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);

      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);

      con.Open();

      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

      OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

      DataTable scores = new DataTable();

      da.Fill(scores);

      dglist.DataSource = scores;

      DataView dv = new DataView(scores);

      dv.RowFilter = string.Format("name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text);

      dglist.DataSource = dv;
```